# Does the following infinite series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Hello does this series converge?

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{tan((\frac{\pi}{4})+(\frac{n\pi}{2}))}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{n}}}$$

I know the top alternates between $\pm1$ but unsure how to proceed.

Comment: I think the $(\frac{n\pi}{2})$ was intended to be inside the expression of $\tan$. No?

Comment: Ah yes apologies.

Comment: changed it sorry.

Comment: @vadim123 I believe the limit comparison test only applies to series of positive terms.

Answer (score 1):

Hint $1$: Prove by induction on $n$ that: $\forall$ $n \ge 0$, $\tan(\frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{n\pi}{2}) = (-1)^n$

Hint $2$: Use the alternating series test.